# Where can I download the Hippacos Catalogue main file and Bright Star Catalogue?

Tags: star-catalogues

I'm developing a software that uses the Hipparcos catalogue. Specifically, I have downloaded this version:

```
I/311               Hipparcos, the New Reduction       (van Leeuwen, 2007)
================================================================================
Hipparcos, the new Reduction of the Raw data
     van Leeuwen F.
    <Astron. Astrophys. 474, 653 (2007)>
    =2007A&A...474..653V
================================================================================
```

But, I need to know the name of the star and the constellation where it is located.

Searching, I've found this [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/8679/7566). Where the author talks about the Hipparcos main catalogue file, the Henry Draper (HD) number of the star and the Bright Star Catalogue.

Where can I download the Hippacos Catalogue main file and Bright Star Catalogue?

Comment: HIPPARCOS and Tycho (click the FTP link)
https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/I/239#/browse

Comment: You found my original question :D Neither of the Hipparcos (1997/2007) files give the constellation, you have to work them out.

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser OK. And how can I do the work out? How can I know which star in the Hipparcos Catalogue is on which constellation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this web to find those catalogues: [CDS Catalogues. Usual Names](https://vizier.cds.unistra.fr/vizier/cats/U.htx)

These are what I was looking for:

> (HIP2) Hipparcos, the New Reduction (van Leeuwen, 2007)  **(I/311)**
>
> (HIP) The Hipparcos and Tycho Catalogues (ESA 1997)  **(I/239)**
>
> (HDE) Henry Draper Catalogue and Extension (Cannon+ 1918-1924; ADC 1989) **(III/135A)**
>
> (HR)  Bright Star Catalogue, 5th Revised Ed. (Hoffleit+, 1991) **(V/50)**

Then, I've used (I/311), (I/239), (III/135A) and (V/50) to find them in this web:

[The Hipparcos and Tycho Catalogues : I/239](https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/I/239#/browse)
[Bright Star Catalogue, 5th Revised Ed. : V/50](https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/V/50#/browse)